# Which profile is workflow/email alerts using

Tags: workflow, email-template, email-alert

We are using an Visualforce email template to send emails via workflow/email alerts. During testing, the email is received. But anything related to data is not populated. Things like `{!relatedTo.FTR__Order__r.Name}`. I am pretty sure the related field values are not empty and I can view them as System Administrator. I thought it was kind of like running in god mode but seems now to me it is not. Do you know where should I set the field security?

Comment: Are you testing this email template from System Administrator profile?

Comment: @Sagar Yes, but shouldn't matter though. Right?

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: Please have a look at this - https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000005093&language=en_US

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be your user:

[image]

Default workflow user would be someone who has all required privileges to function properly.